# Trying to click on the <Button> tag , in selenium web driver using python

Tags: html, python-2.7, selenium-webdriver

I have been trying to click on a button for the following html by using python (selenium webdriver)

```
<div class="cssm-TopNav_printIcon_2VzB_">

<button type="button" aria-label="Print" title="Print" class="cssm-Button_button_2a549 cssm-Button_secondary_22F7i cssm-Button_sm_EPQ2U">
<div class="" aria-hidden="true" color="black" style="display: inline-block; height: 16px; width: 16px; min-height: 16px; min-width: 16px; max-height: 16px; max-width: 16px;">
<svg viewBox="0 0 24 24" class="" focusable="false">
<g fill="#3C3F51">
<path d="M19 8H5c-1.66 0-3 1.34-3 3v6h4v4h12v-4h4v-6c0-1.66-1.34-3-3-3zm-3 11H8v-5h8v5zm3-7c-.55 0-1-.45-1-1s.45-1 1-1 1 .45 1 1-.45 1-1 1zm-1-9H6v4h12V3z">
</path>
<path d="M0 0h24v24H0z" fill="none">
</path></g></svg></div></button>

<button type="button" class="cssm-Button_button_2a549 cssm-Button_primary_1gH9y cssm-Button_sm_EPQ2U">
<!-- react-text: 314 -->View Custody List<!-- /react-text -->
</button>
```

I am trying to click on the second button in the above html.

I am using **find_element_by_tag** because i think for html `<button>` tag it should work .I am using following code snippet to click on it , but getting-:**element not visible**

```
driver.find_element_by_tag_name("button").click()
```

Any help will be appreciated!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Selenium with Python documentation UnOfficial](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/)

Hii there

Selenium provides the following methods to locate elements in a page:

```
find_element_by_id
find_element_by_name
find_element_by_xpath
find_element_by_link_text
find_element_by_partial_link_text
find_element_by_tag_name
find_element_by_class_name
find_element_by_css_selector
```

To find multiple elements (these methods will return a list):

```
find_elements_by_name
find_elements_by_xpath
find_elements_by_link_text
find_elements_by_partial_link_text
find_elements_by_tag_name
find_elements_by_class_name
find_elements_by_css_selector
```

**this is how your code should be**

```
#this code will get the list of tags and select the second tag from the list
element = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('button')[1] 
#this will click the element
element.click()
```

Comment: This way of finding elements is now deprecated in Selenium 4. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/69875984/2154717. The answer is still correct for Selenium 3.

Answer (score 0):

There is probably more than one button tag on the page, try to be more explicit, like:

```
driver.find_element_by_class_name("cssm-Button_primary_1gH9y").click()
```

or even better, give the button an ID and use

```
driver.find_element_by_id("the-button-id").click()
```

Comment: Thanks fo ryour reply , yes you are right and there are two html button and I have used find_element_by tag and find_elements_by_tag, both to acsess it .but still cant click on the second button

Comment: Are you able to give the button an id and click on that?

Comment: hey !! thanks anthony, the code snippet you have provided `driver.find_element_by_class_name("cssm-Button_primary_1gH9y").click()` ..it worked for me , i am new to selenium and still clueless about why my ***find_Element_by_tag*** is not working? I agree there are 2 buttons on the page but as per the selenium , it must have clicked  on the first button which is available to it while rendering the page , but in my case none of them is clicked .

Comment: No problem - I'm glad it helped.  The error is giving an indication of what is happening.  The first button selenium is encountering is invisible, so unclickable.