# find_element_by_* commands are deprecated in Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, findelement

When starting the function

```
def run(driver_path):
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=driver_path)
    driver.get('https://tproger.ru/quiz/real-programmer/')
    button = driver.find_element_by_class_name("quiz_button")
    button.click()
run(driver_path)
```

I'm getting errors like these:

```
<ipython-input-27-c5a7960e105f>:6: DeprecationWarning: executable_path has been deprecated, please pass in a Service object
  driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=driver_path)
<ipython-input-27-c5a7960e105f>:10: DeprecationWarning: find_element_by_* commands are deprecated. Please use find_element() instead
  button = driver.find_element_by_class_name("quiz_button")
```

... but I can't understand why.

I'm using [WebDriver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selenium_(software)#Selenium_WebDriver) at the latest version for my Chrome's version. I don't why I get

```
find_element_by_* commands are deprecated
```

... when it's in the documentation that the command exists.

Comment: Try checking this one. Matches your query. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61308799/unable-to-locate-elements-in-selenium-python

Answer (score 204, accepted):

This error message...

```
DeprecationWarning: find_element_by_* commands are deprecated. Please use find_element() instead
```

...implies that the *`find_element_by_*`* commands are deprecated in the latest Selenium Python libraries.

As [AutomatedTester mentions](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/8806#issuecomment-711947184): This *DeprecationWarning* was the reflection of the changes made with respect to the decision to simplify the APIs across the languages and this does that.

---

### Solution

Instead you have to use *`find_element()`*. As an example:

> You have to include the following imports
>
> ```
> from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
> ```

- Using `class_name`:

  ```
  button = driver.find_element_by_class_name("quiz_button")
  ```

  Needs be replaced with:

  ```
  button = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "quiz_button")
  ```

---

Along the lines of, you also have to change the following:

- Using `id`:

  ```
  element = find_element_by_id("element_id")
  ```

  Needs be replaced with:

  ```
  element = driver.find_element(By.ID, "element_id")
  ```
- Using `name`:

  ```
  element = find_element_by_name("element_name")
  ```

  Needs be replaced with:

  ```
  element = driver.find_element(By.NAME, "element_name")
  ```
- Using `link_text`:

  ```
  element = find_element_by_link_text("element_link_text")
  ```

  Needs be replaced with:

  ```
  element = driver.find_element(By.LINK_TEXT, "element_link_text")
  ```
- Using `partial_link_text`:

  ```
  element = find_element_by_partial_link_text("element_partial_link_text")
  ```

  Needs be replaced with:

  ```
  element = driver.find_element(By.PARTIAL_LINK_TEXT, "element_partial_link_text")
  ```
- Using `tag_name`:

  ```
  element = find_element_by_tag_name("element_tag_name")
  ```

  Needs be replaced with:

  ```
  element = driver.find_element(By.TAG_NAME, "element_tag_name")
  ```
- Using `css_selector`:

  ```
  element = find_element_by_css_selector("element_css_selector")
  ```

  Needs be replaced with:

  ```
  element = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "element_css_selector")
  ```
- Using `xpath`:

  ```
  element = find_element_by_xpath("element_xpath")
  ```

  Needs be replaced with:

  ```
  element = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "element_xpath")
  ```

**Note:** If you are searching and replacing to implement the above changes, you will need to do the same thing for `find_elements_*`, i.e., the plural forms of `find_element_*`.

You may also find this upgrade guide useful as it covers some other unrelated changes you may need to make when upgrading: *[Upgrade to Selenium 4](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/getting_started/upgrade_to_selenium_4/)*

Comment: NameError: name 'By' is not defined

Comment: from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

Comment: This is great, this is alot of the commands in the recent new slightly different syntax. But what i see missing is the "send_keys". also on the Selenium website, they don't have an example yet for the "Send_Keys" but invite anyone to contribute an example. https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/actions_api/keyboard/#send-keys  , also if you can put a send_keys example here in your answer . currently i'm attempting the send_keys with driver.find_element(By.ID, 'element_name') example. if you can put that there, that would be great. Thanks,

Comment: What about this - emailaddress_input = driver.find_elements_by_xpath(x_path)[index], how can I provide index if I replace find_elements_by_xpath with find_element* function.

Comment: Vim users can use this quick-and-dirty substitution to capture all of this: :%s/find_element\([s]*\)_by_\([^(]*\)(/find_element\1(By.\U\2, /g

Answer (score 10):

@DebanjanB mentioned and explained the new structure. Also, it's better use these lines:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service

s = Service('C:/Users/.../chromedriver.exe')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=s)
```

Comment: What are `keys` for in this example?

Comment: @Arete, By and Key will be used to detect target and input data! , these lines are the main structure .

Comment: *Why* is it better? Please respond by [editing (changing) your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/69893455/edit), not here in comments (************** ***without*** ************** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today).

Comment: Who is DebanjanB? What does it refer to? An answer to this question? A comment to this question? In some other Stack Overflow question? Something else?

Answer (score 4):

As others mentioned, you should use `find_element()` or `find_elements()` instead of `find_element_by_*()` or `find_elements_by_*()`.

I wrote the regex pattern to replace the deprecated methods to new ones, so try this if you need.

```
# from - e.g. find_element_by_id("test")

find_element(s?)_by_([a-z]+)\((.*)

# to - e.g. find_element(By.ID, "test")

find_element$1(By.\U$2\E, $3
```

Note: you need the import line to use the new methods

```py
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
```

Comment: Here's a couple handy one liners to run before and after running the regex replace `egrep 'find_element(s?)_by_([a-z]+)\((.*)' -R . | grep -v venv | cut -f1 -d: | sort -u | tee -a update-these.txt | xargs -I{} bash -c 'echo -e "from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By\n$(cat {})" > {}'` AND to check that the imports were added to the files to update `cat update-these.txt | xargs head -n 1`

Comment: Re *"regex pattern to replace the deprecated methods"*: Applied in what context? A Perl script? In a text editor?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @Stephen and [*undetected Selenium* for your answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69875125/find-element-by-commands-are-deprecated-in-selenium/69875984#69875984). After some time reading on how where to find an example of `send_key`, I found an amazing [gist of examples](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/seleniumhq.github.io/blob/trunk/examples/python/tests/actions_api/test_keys.py#L10-L1).

The `send_keys` below example worked for me:

```
browser = webdriver.Chrome()
```

```
def test_key_down(driver):
    driver.get('https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/web/single_text_input.html?#')

    ActionChains(driver) \
        .send_keys("abc") \
        .perform()
```

`test_key_down(browser)`

Comment: There isn't anybody here with the name "Stephen". What answer does it refer to?