# What is the difference between "find_element_by_name('name')" and "find_element(By.NAME, 'name')"?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

**Examples:**

```
# method 1
from selenium import webdriver

PATH = '...'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)
driver.get('https://google.com')
driver.find_element_by_name('q').send_keys('test')
```

```
# method 2
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

PATH = 'c:\\Program Files (x86)\\chromedriver.exe'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)
driver.get('https://google.com')
driver.find_element(By.NAME, 'q').send_keys('test')
```

Basically, I want to know:

1 - Are there differences between the two? If there are, what are they?

2 - Generally speaking, are there differences between these?

```
find_element_by_class_name(el): find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, el); 

find_element_by_name(el): find_element(By.NAME, el)
```

3 - Why is a `DeprecationWarning` shown when the first method is executed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @GuiHva also mentioned, there is no difference between the two lines:

```
driver.find_element_by_name('q')
```

and

```
driver.find_element(By.NAME, 'q')
```

as in the current release of [selenium4](/questions/tagged/selenium4) *Python* client [**`find_element_by_name(name)`**](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_remote/selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.WebDriver.find_element_by_name) under the hood still invokes:

```
self.find_element(by=By.NAME, value=name)
```

but along with a [*DeprecationWarning*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69875125/find-element-by-commands-are-deprecated-in-selenium/69875984#69875984).

The current implementation of [find_element_by_name()](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/py/_modules/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.html#WebDriver.find_element_by_name) is as follows:

```
def find_element_by_name(self, name) -> WebElement:
    """
    Finds an element by name.

    :Args:
     - name: The name of the element to find.

    :Returns:
     - WebElement - the element if it was found

    :Raises:
     - NoSuchElementException - if the element wasn't found

    :Usage:
        ::

            element = driver.find_element_by_name('foo')
    """
    warnings.warn(
        "find_element_by_* commands are deprecated. Please use find_element() instead",
        DeprecationWarning,
        stacklevel=2,
    )
    return self.find_element(by=By.NAME, value=name)
```

---

### Why this change

As *`@AutomatedTester`* [mentions](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/8806#issuecomment-711947184):

> > The decision was to simplify the APIs across the languages and this does that.

Answer (score 1):

They are the same, the `find_element_by_name` call `find_element` method and pass `By.NAME` to `by` arguments.
This is the source code:

```
def find_element_by_name(self, name):
    """
    Finds an element by name.

    :Args:
     - name: The name of the element to find.

    :Returns:
     - WebElement - the element if it was found

    :Raises:
     - NoSuchElementException - if the element wasn't found

    :Usage:
        element = driver.find_element_by_name('foo')
    """
    return self.find_element(by=By.NAME, value=name)
```

All the `find_element_by_*` methods are call `find_element` method with different `by` arguments.
You should go to see selenium `webdriver` class sourcecode for detail.

This is selenium official api doc. https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/py/_modules/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.html#WebDriver

Comment: Everything you said is correct but I would recommend using `find_element()` and pass in locators. It makes your code much easier to maintain.

Comment: yes, i would prefer `find_element` as well