# DeprecationWarning: find_elements_by_* commands are deprecated. Please use find_elements() instead using Selenium in Google Colab

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, google-colaboratory, selenium4, selenium-webdriver-python

There are a few functions that work with selenium and these functions have certain outputs, but when I open them in google colab, I get a few outputs that I don't want, it reduces the understanding.

```
BETSWITSBOT

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/ipykernel_launcher.py:4: DeprecationWarning: find_elements_by_* commands are deprecated. Please use find_elements() instead
  after removing the cwd from sys.path.
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/ipykernel_launcher.py:5: DeprecationWarning: find_elements_by_* commands are deprecated. Please use find_elements() instead
  """
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/ipykernel_launcher.py:6: DeprecationWarning: find_elements_by_* commands are deprecated. Please use find_elements() instead
  
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/ipykernel_launcher.py:7: DeprecationWarning: find_elements_by_* commands are deprecated. Please use find_elements() instead
  import sys
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/ipykernel_launcher.py:8: DeprecationWarning: find_elements_by_* commands are deprecated. Please use find_elements() instead
  
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/ipykernel_launcher.py:9: DeprecationWarning: find_elements_by_* commands are deprecated. Please use find_elements() instead
  if __name__ == '__main__':
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/ipykernel_launcher.py:10: DeprecationWarning: find_elements_by_* commands are deprecated. Please use find_elements() instead
  # Remove the CWD from sys.path while we load stuff.
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/ipykernel_launcher.py:11: DeprecationWarning: find_elements_by_* commands are deprecated. Please use find_elements() instead
  # This is added back by InteractiveShellApp.init_path()
Hatayspor
Feyenoord
Nice
Aris
Antalyaspor
PSV
Arsenal
```

Is there a way to not get the output between 'BETSWITHBOT' and 'HATAYSPOR' in the example?

My code :

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as ec
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
driver = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver',chrome_options=chrome_options)

def betswitsbot():
    print("BETSWITSBOT\n")
    driver.get("https://www.betswithbots.com/")
    takimlar = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//table[@id='predictions_table']/tbody/tr/td[3]")
    evTahmin = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//table[@id='predictions_table']/tbody/tr/td[4]")
    xTahmin = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//table[@id='predictions_table']/tbody/tr/td[5]")
    depTahmin = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//table[@id='predictions_table']/tbody/tr/td[6]")
    altTahmin = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//table[@id='predictions_table']/tbody/tr/td[7]")
    ustTahmin = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//table[@id='predictions_table']/tbody/tr/td[8]")
    ngTahmin = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//table[@id='predictions_table']/tbody/tr/td[9]")
    gTahmin = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//table[@id='predictions_table']/tbody/tr/td[10]")

    for x in range(0,len(takimlar)):
        try:
            ev, dep = takimlar[x].text.split(" - ")
            #print(ev, evTahmin[x].text, xTahmin[x].text, depTahmin[x].text, dep, altTahmin[x].text, ustTahmin[x].text, ngTahmin[x].text, gTahmin[x].text, sep="\t")
            if float(evTahmin[x].text) > 50:
                print(ev)
            elif float(depTahmin[x].text) > 50:
                print(dep)
        except:
            a=0

betswitsbot()
```

Comment: We can't guess what is your problem without seeing your code

Comment: I added the code, in the output part i don't want "/usr/local..." texts

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These [DeprecationWarning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69875125/find-element-by-commands-are-deprecated-in-selenium/69875984#69875984) logs...

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/ipykernel_launcher.py:4: DeprecationWarning: find_elements_by_* commands are deprecated. Please use find_elements() instead
...
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/ipykernel_launcher.py:5: DeprecationWarning: find_elements_by_* commands are deprecated. Please use find_elements() instead
...
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/ipykernel_launcher.py:10: DeprecationWarning: find_elements_by_* commands are deprecated. Please use find_elements() instead
```

...is the result of the change in the latest version of [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54459701/what-is-selenium-and-what-is-webdriver/54482491#54482491) which is inline with the **Selenium 4 Release Candidate 1** [changelog](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/d6acda7c0254f9681574bf4078ff2001705bf940/py/CHANGES#L32) which mentions:

> Specify that the "find_element_by_* ..." warning is a deprecation warning (#9700)

---

### Solution

Instead of *`find_element_by_*`* you have to use *`find_element()`*. As an example:

> > You need to add the following import:
> >
> > ```
> > from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
> > ```

- Instead of using:

  ```
  takimlar = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//table[@id='predictions_table']/tbody/tr/td[3]")
  ```
- You need to use:

  ```
  takimlar = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//table[@id='predictions_table']/tbody/tr/td[3]")
  ```

---

### References

You can find a couple of relevant detailed discussions in:

- [What is the difference between "find_element_by_name('name')" and "find_element(By.NAME, 'name')"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70718458/what-is-the-difference-between-find-element-by-namename-and-find-element/70725928#70725928)
- [Unable to locate elements in Selenium (Python)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61308799/unable-to-locate-elements-in-selenium-python/69963351#69963351)

Comment: thank you, i never thought there would be a change in selenium