# Finding all possible button elements in Selenium python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, findelement

I am trying to get all buttons from a website but it seems the Selenium syntax has changed without the docs being updated. I am trying to get the buttons from the website as follows:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()))
url = 'https://www.programiz.com/python-programming'
driver.get(url)
buttons = driver.find_element(by=By.TAG_NAME("button"))
```

However I get the following error:

```
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

As mentioned the docs still say to use `find_element_by_tag_name` which is depreciated. Can someone help please. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`find_element_by_*` commands are [depreciated](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69875984/7429447) now.

To find all the *`<button>`* elements you can use the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver):

- Using *tag_name*:

  ```
  buttons = driver.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, "button")
  ```
- Using *css_selector*:

  ```
  buttons = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button")
  ```
- Using *xpath*:

  ```
  buttons = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//button")
  ```

Answer (score 1):

Problem is with TAG_NAME it is just constant not a callable method,
new usage by docs should be:

```py
driver.find_element(By.TAG_NAME, 'button')
```

Checked docs here https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/py/index.html#example-1