# WebDriverException: 'css selector' is not valid or implemented searching strategy error in automation of windows application using Winium

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, winium

I'm new to the winium and trying to automate the process. every time i run the code im getting an error:

```
WebDriverException: 'css selector' is not valid or implemented searching strategy.
```

Below is my code:-

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

# starting the file 
os.startfile(r'C:\Users\RTamb\Desktop\python basics\web scraping\winium\Winium.Desktop.Driver\Winium.Desktop.Driver.exe')

driver = webdriver.Remote(command_executor='http://localhost:9999',
desired_capabilities={"debugConnectToRunningApp": 'false',
'app': r'C:\Users\RTamb\Desktop\BO\All Cases (V1.0 New Final Build)_New.rep',
'args': '-port 345'})


driver.find_element_by_id('Edit').click()
```

I have tried tried multiple method like `.find_element_by_name()`, `find_element_by_class_name`, `find_element_by_css_selector()`

Answer (score 0):

This error message...

```
WebDriverException: 'css selector' is not valid or implemented searching strategy.
```

...implies that the searching strategy you have used is not a valid [locator strategy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver)

With the availability of [selenium4](/questions/tagged/selenium4) [find_element_by_* commands are deprecated](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69875125/7429447).

Accordlingly, instead of:

```
driver.find_element_by_id('Edit').click()
```

You have to:

```
driver.find_element(By.ID, "Edit").click()
```