# Python selenium is neither not looking for id nor selecting button or giving input

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, bots

So when I am execute my code the website will be open but the other steps which I described in my code below are not be execute, why? I even tried time.sleep() after the website is loaded in order to execute the remaining code but it is not working.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time


driver = webdriver.Chrome('/Users/User/Desktop/it_projects/python-google-automation/Neuer Ordner/chromedriver')

#open certain website
driver.get('https://www.nike.com/de/?cp=58194921917_search_%7cnike%7c10594878138%7c107792850434%7ce%7cc%7cDE%7cpure%7c452291007809&ds_rl=1252249&gclid=EAIaIQobChMIod-_o8jD-QIVE4XVCh1-FggsEAAYASAAEgJSYfD_BwE&gclsrc=aw.ds')



#go through cookie process
evade_cookie = driver.find_element_by_id('hf_cookie_text_moreInformation') #search for cookie-button (more informations)
evade_cookie.send_keys(Keys.RETURN) #click on button
select_cookie = driver.find_element_by_id('hf_cookie_label_done') #search for done-button
select_cookie.send_keys(Keys.RETURN) #click on done-button 

#search for Sneakers
search = driver.find_element_by_id('VisualSearchInput') #search for input-area
search.send_keys('Nike Dunk Low') #insert input
search.send_keys(Keys.RETURN) #enter or return respectively
```

```
Error
/Users/user/Desktop/it_projects/python-google-automation/Neuer Ordner/main.py:6: DeprecationWarning: executable_path has been deprecated, please pass in a Service object
  driver = webdriver.Chrome('/Users/user/Desktop/it_projects/python-google-automation/Neuer Ordner/chromedriver')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/user/Desktop/it_projects/python-google-automation/Neuer Ordner/main.py", line 14, in <module>
    evade_cookie = driver.find_element_by_id('hf_cookie_text_moreInformation') #search for cookie-button (more informations)
AttributeError: 'WebDriver' object has no attribute 'find_element_by_id'
user@MacBook-Air-von-Sami python-google-automation %
```

Comment: Looks like you have not defined a 'wait', so selenium is not waiting for the elements to be loaded. You can read about waits here: https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/waits/.

Comment: I tried this way too but this did not work

Comment: Do you have a particular reason for not accepting all cookies, so you can move on with your other tasks on that websote?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the syntax you are using is incorrect.

Try the below code

```
#go through cookie process
evade_cookie = driver.find_element('id','hf_cookie_text_moreInformation') #search for cookie-button (more informations)
evade_cookie.send_keys(Keys.RETURN) #click on button
select_cookie = driver.find_element('id','hf_cookie_label_done') #search for done-button
select_cookie.send_keys(Keys.RETURN) #click on done-button
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code will properly wait for the elements to be clickable, and execute correctly. The setup is Firefox/geckodriver on Linux, but you can adapt it to your own, just observe the imports, and the part after defining the browser/driver:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options as Firefox_Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time as t

firefox_options = Firefox_Options()

driverService = Service('chromedriver/geckodriver')

browser = webdriver.Firefox(service=driverService, options=firefox_options)

url = 'https://www.nike.com/de/?cp=58194921917_search_%7cnike%7c10594878138%7c107792850434%7ce%7cc%7cDE%7cpure%7c452291007809&ds_rl=1252249&gclid=EAIaIQobChMIod-_o8jD-QIVE4XVCh1-FggsEAAYASAAEgJSYfD_BwE&gclsrc=aw.ds'

browser.get(url) 

WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,'//span[text()="Mehr Informationen"]'))).click()
WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,'//span[text()="Fertig"]'))).click()

search_box = WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID,'VisualSearchInput')))
search_box.send_keys('Nike Dunk Low')
t.sleep(1)
search_box.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
```

Selenium documentation: https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/

Answer (score 0):

As per the error stacktrace there are two errors:

- *DeprecationWarning: executable_path has been deprecated, please pass in a Service object*: Implies that the default argument `executable_path` is deprecated now and you have to use an instance of the `Service()` class. See: [DeprecationWarning: executable_path has been deprecated selenium python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64717302/7429447)
- *AttributeError: 'WebDriver' object has no attribute 'find_element_by_id'*: Implies that the `find_element_by_*` commands are deprecated in the latest Selenium Python libraries. Instead you have to use `find_element()`. See: [find_element_by_* commands are deprecated in selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69875125/7429447)

Your effective code block will be:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service

s = Service('/Users/User/Desktop/it_projects/python-google-automation/Neuer Ordner/chromedriver')
driver = = webdriver.Chrome(service=s)
driver.get('https://www.nike.com/de/?cp=58194921917_search_%7cnike%7c10594878138%7c107792850434%7ce%7cc%7cDE%7cpure%7c452291007809&ds_rl=1252249&gclid=EAIaIQobChMIod-_o8jD-QIVE4XVCh1-FggsEAAYASAAEgJSYfD_BwE&gclsrc=aw.ds')
evade_cookie = driver.find_element(By.ID, "hf_cookie_text_moreInformation")
```