# while running python fuf.py in cmd i got this error

Tags: python, instapy

```
C:\Users\User\Desktop\IG-Bot-main\fuf.py:17: DeprecationWarning: executable_path has been deprecated, please pass in a Service object
  browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=ChromeDriverManager().install(), options=options)

DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:54066/devtools/browser/be5feff5-fcc3-4e54-be84-b2c6a88ff51f
[6332:6584:1029/085024.281:ERROR:device_event_log_impl.cc(215)] [08:50:24.280] USB: usb_device_handle_win.cc:1048 Failed to read descriptor from node connection: A device attached to the system is not functioning. (0x1F)
[6332:6584:1029/085024.283:ERROR:device_event_log_impl.cc(215)] [08:50:24.281] USB: usb_device_handle_win.cc:1048 Failed to read descriptor from node connection: A device attached to the system is not functioning. (0x1F)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\IG-Bot-main\fuf.py", line 73, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\IG-Bot-main\fuf.py", line 21, in main
    username_input = browser.find_element_by_css_selector("input[name='username']")
AttributeError: 'WebDriver' object has no attribute 'find_element_by_css_selector'
```

i updated pip
installed 'packaging'
but still recieving the same error

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I can see in the error that your code is using ```find_element_by_css_selector``` from Selenium library. I think this is deprecated. Instead you have to use ```find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "css selector")```

Comment: This may help: https://stackoverflow.com/q/69875125/3216427