# cannot find chrome binary while running code

Tags: python, selenium, automation

I am so new to python and selenium
I am trying to make a script that checks if an element (date in a datepicker) is enabled or disabled

I always get this error :
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: cannot find Chrome binary

this is the code :

```
import datetime
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

driver_service = Service(executable_path=r"C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\Test\chromedriver.exe")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=driver_service)
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.binary_location = r"C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe"


url = "URL"
browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\Test\chromedriver.exe")
browser.get(url)



def next_7_dates():
    today = datetime.datetime.today()
    date_list = []
    for x in range(0,7):
        new_date = today + datetime.timedelta(days=x)
        date_list.append(new_date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))
    return date_list



Available_date = browser.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[1]/span/form/div/div[2]/div[8]")
Free = find_element_by_class_name("bg-disabled")
if Free.is_enabled():
     print("No Appointments available")
```

I am new to I am pretty much testing stuff

Comment: Are you sure Chrome is in "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe"? If not, change `options.binary_location` to correct path.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69875125/find-element-by-commands-are-deprecated-in-selenium

Comment: @СергейКох I have already followed these instructions but the error still exists,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were almost there. You just need to supply the arguments properly and supply the lines of code in proper sequence as follows:

```
driver_service = Service(r"C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\Test\chromedriver.exe")
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.binary_location = r"C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=driver_service, , options=options)
url = "URL"
browser.get(url)
```

Comment: I have already edited the code as above but this error occurs.. selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited normally.
  (unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)
  (The process started from chrome location C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)

Comment: Great, so are no more seeing _`Message: unknown error: cannot find Chrome binary`_. For  this _**`unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist`**_ error have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50642913/7429447) discussion.