# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'send_keys'....plz rply

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driver = webdriver.Chrome(r"C:\Users\ram.sn\Desktop\New folder\chromedriver_win32 (2)\chromedriver.exe")

driver.get("https://www.nopcommerce.com/en/login")

driver.find_element_by_id("Username").send_keys("test")
```

Error:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'send_keys'
```

Comment: If possible, please provide link to webpage you're testing and the code needed to fix using StackOverflow's editor.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the driver in not None.

```
if driver == None:
    Logger.info('Driver is none')
```

Also, make sure that you actually found the element

```
element = driver.find_element_by_id("Username")
if element == None:
    Logger.info('element is none')
else:
    element.send_keys('test')
```

Answer (score 0):

[`find_element_by_*` commands are deprecated](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69875984/7429447) now. So you have to replace:

```
driver.find_element_by_id("Username").send_keys("test")
```

with

```
driver.find_element(By.ID, "Username").send_keys("test")
```