# Cannot close pop up in selenium using xpath

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, xpath

I'm trying to close a pop up using xpath but I am failing:

The website: https://www.zhihu.com/question/42867599

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[5]/div/div/div/div[2]/button/svg").click()
```

I got the xpath from firefox, so I don't know what is wrong here. The image of the page is added.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

##### Use this `Xpath`:

```
'//button[@class="Button Modal-closeButton Button--plain"]'
```

Clicking on the `svg` element is pointless, because the event listener is on the `button`.

Auto-generated `XPath` by the browser sucks, they are not reliable querys.

Take a look at my own project to craft more specific `XPath` (or even `CSS` selectors) more easily and with better querys:
https://github.com/sputnick-dev/retrieveCssOrXpathSelectorFromTextOrNode

You can even makes the `XPath` more reliable like this (partial match):

```
'//button[contains(@class, "closeButton")]'
```

you also can use text from attribute:

```
'//button[@aria-label="关闭"]'
```

Choose the one that seems the more reliable in your situation. You also can keep commented other versions if something will change from within the page.

##### tested in Chromium:

```
$x('//button[@class="Button Modal-closeButton Button--plain"]')[0].click()
```

##### Note:

`find_element_by_xpath(selector)` method is deprecated in `Selenium 4` and you should use instead:

```
selector = '//button[contains(@class, "closeButton")]'
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
find_element(By.XPATH, selector)
```

See: [find_element_by_* commands are deprecated in Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69875125/find-element-by-commands-are-deprecated-in-selenium)

Comment: This worked, thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

Copying an XPath using the browser dev tools and using it directly many times results in very brittle XPaths. Any XPath that starts with `/html` or contains indices, e.g. `div[5]` is likely to be brittle... small changes to the page have a good chance to break the locator. Instead create custom locators and prefer CSS selectors. CSS selectors are faster, better supported, simpler syntax, and easier to read. XPaths have their place... they are the only locator type that can locate an element by contained text or do complex DOM traversal.

A simpler way to close that dialog is to use the CSS selector,

```
button[aria-label='关闭']
```

Be very careful with other answers that suggest that you use an XPath with `@class=''`. That is doing an exact string match which will fail if there's any change in the class, e.g. a class is added or removed from the element. The CSS selector I posted above is not affected by class changes.

Also, you'll want to update your `find_element` syntax to the new format,

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "css selector")
find_element(By.XPATH, "xpath")
```

See [the docs](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html).

Comment: `aria-label` attribute name can change too. Usually, a well crafted XPath is more reliable than a CSS selector. XPath is quite more advanced than limited CSS. Moreover, OP asked XPath. My Xpath solution is more reliable `'//button[contains(@class, "closeButton")]'` and I provided alternative robust querys

Comment: @GillesQuénot 1. The `aria-label` *could* change but in my experience, it's a LOT less likely to because it's there to help screen readers, etc. which means that the purpose of the element would have to change and at that point, all bets are off for all locators. The class could change for any number of reasons.

Comment: 2. "Usually, a well crafted XPath is more reliable than a CSS selector." No it's not and you have no evidence to prove such a statement. Other than the 2 cases I mentioned in my answer, CSS selectors are exactly equivalent (or better) to XPath but in the case we're discussing, CSS selectors have a distinct advantage. XPath's `@class='...'` that you are using is an exact string match for the full class meaning that the tiniest change to any class or class name would break that locator. Even reordering the existing class names would break your locator.

Comment: The CSS selector, `button.Modal-closeButton` is a lot more resilient than the XPath you used... along with shorter, easier to read, simpler, etc.

Comment: 3. "My Xpath solution is more reliable '//button[contains(@class, "closeButton")]'". No, it's not. See #1, above.

Comment: It's also interesting that you copied half the content of my answer...

Comment: You chose CSS, I took XPath. Any issue? Was there before, for information, who copy the other? It's easy to make something after a relevant answer to capitalize the logic to enhance it as you want.