find_elements_by_class_name & all other find_elements_by functions doesn't exist
So I got Selenium installed but somehow the find_elements_by_class_name & all other find_elements_by functions doesn't exist. Only find_elements() and find_element() exists.
Hope someone can help out. Thanks!
Tried closing and reinstalling PyCharm but still all other find_element functions do not exist.

There was a similar question already. Here is the link to it with the answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69875125/find-element-by-commands-are-deprecated-in-selenium

I assume that you are using Selenium 4. In selenium 4, All find_elements_* APIs are replaced with find_elements. Here is how you could achieve the same functionality with the new APIs.
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

# By Class Name
driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, 'your_class_name')
# By ID
driver.find_elements(By.ID, 'your_id')
# By Name
driver.find_elements(By.NAME, "your_element_name")


You have to use find_element(). As an example:

You have to include the following imports
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By



Using class_name:
button = driver.find_element_by_class_name("quiz_button")

Needs be replaced with:
button = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "quiz_button")




Along the lines of, you also have to change the following:

Using id:
element = find_element_by_id("element_id")

Needs be replaced with:
element = driver.find_element(By.ID, "element_id")


Using name:
element = find_element_by_name("element_name")

Needs be replaced with:
element = driver.find_element(By.NAME, "element_name")


Using link_text:
element = find_element_by_link_text("element_link_text")

Needs be replaced with:
element = driver.find_element(By.LINK_TEXT, "element_link_text")


Using partial_link_text:
element = find_element_by_partial_link_text("element_partial_link_text")

Needs be replaced with:
element = driver.find_element(By.PARTIAL_LINK_TEXT, "element_partial_link_text")


Using tag_name:
element = find_element_by_tag_name("element_tag_name")

Needs be replaced with:
element = driver.find_element(By.TAG_NAME, "element_tag_name")


Using css_selector:
element = find_element_by_css_selector("element_css_selector")

Needs be replaced with:
element = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "element_css_selector")


Using xpath:
element = find_element_by_xpath("element_xpath")

Needs be replaced with:
element = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "element_xpath")




Prior to version 4.0.0, it was feasible to address it that way. However, starting from version 4.0.0, you must utilize this new format:
find_element(By.CLASSNAME,"tomatoes")
find_elements(By.CLASSNAME,"tomatoes")

https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/elements/finders/
https://pypi.org/project/selenium/#history

wow thanks. I hope this works out.

I'm having this error now.
NameError: name 'By' is not defined
After  trying this code:
browser.find_element(By.Name,"controls")
